# drf_yasg rest_framework_simplejwt JWTAuthentication not work

Tags: django-rest-framework-simplejwt, drf-yasg

settings.py

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
```

views.py

```
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg import openapi

schema_view = get_schema_view(
   openapi.Info(
      title="接口文档",
      default_version='v1',
      description="使用youtube-dl 下载视频",
      contact=openapi.Contact(email="wh970305@163.com"),
   ),
   public=True,

)
```

then the API return Authentication credentials were not provided.
because the token is wrong

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/info" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNDU2" -H  "X-CSRFToken: TQ31NEGiMUJVUvqJKVKyua1hWgmHP614t0skwPqxQT0JvUR8PMqzXgIqAKzcgEhW"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way: `Authorization: Bearer JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN`